# Alexa Skill from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, alexa-skills-kit

First of all, sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any info after searching for a while

I want to code an Alexa skill from VSCode using Python, as I prefer it rather than coding on the browser. I tried following the steps on "offline tools"([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E5xR.jpg)) but I've been struggling to get it working

### Option A, extension:

When I open the *Alexa Skill Toolkit(ASK)* VSCode extension, sign in and try to import my existing project, it asks for some git credentials which I couldn't get after following [this tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-hosted-skill.html).

- Manually making the petition from Python ends up with a 401 Response
  (I don't know what the value of the *Authorization* header should
  be)
- Executing `ask util git-credentials-helper` didn't work either

### Option B, CLI:

After installing NodeJS and ASK-CLI, i get a **could not fetch origin error** using
`ask init --hosted-skill-id amzn1.ask.skill.myId`

I probably just made a lot of dumb mistakes but I'm really confused rigth now, thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "401" error code means you are unauthorized. I'm assuming you didn't try to put anything in that header because you didn't what what you should have put there. Here's a guide to get an access token for your authorization header: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/get-access-token-smapi.html